# Scrape content from a webpage

Tags: php, html, scrape

I'm trying to scrap content from this webpage:

www.motorcyclemonster.com/motorcycle-events.html, the code I'm using is:

```
<?php  

    $content = file_get_contents('http://www.motorcyclemonster.com/motorcycle-events.html');

    $pattern = '#<tr.">\r\n<td>(.*)</td>\r\n<td>(.*)</td>#';

    preg_match_all ($pattern, $content, $data);

    var_dump($data);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++)
    {
        echo "<br /><br />". $data[2][$i].' '.$data[3][$i];
    }

?>
```

I would just like to be able to pull information from the following

```
<tr>
    <td width="23%" bgcolor="#76C2FA">Nov 15 - Jan 4</td>
    <td width="52%" bgcolor="#76C2FA"><b> <a href="/events/cars-and-christmas-2014-11-15-Hershey-PA.html" title="Cars and Christmas - Hershey, Pennsylvania">Cars and Christmas</a></b></td>
    <td width="20%" bgcolor="#76C2FA">Hershey</td>
    <td width="5%" bgcolor="#76C2FA">PA</td>
</tr>
```

and the be able to set up some variables for

```
<tr>
    <td width="23%" bgcolor="#76C2FA">**$date**</td>
    <td width="52%" bgcolor="#76C2FA"><b><a href=**$page_url**" title="**$title**">$title</a></b></td>
    <td width="20%" bgcolor="#76C2FA">**$city**</td>
    <td width="5%" bgcolor="#76C2FA">**$state**</td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML tags with regular expressions is not such a great idea (for a wide range of reasons). I would rather suggest checking [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), as it is specifically done for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using [PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Adrian
 * Date: 05/12/2014
 * Time: 19:28
 */
//Load website

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.motorcyclemonster.com/motorcycle-events.html');

//For each table row
$events = array();
foreach($html->find('table',2)->find('tr') as $h){
    $temp = array();
    //get date
    $temp['date'] = $h->find('td', 0)->innertext; //Inner contents of first cell

    if($url = $h->find('td', 1)) {
        if($url = $url->find('a', 0)) {//First link of second cell
            $temp['url'] = $url->href; //href attribute
            $temp['url_title'] = $url->title; //title attribute
            $temp['title'] = $url->innertext; // Inner content of link

            $temp['town'] = $h->find('td', 2)->innertext;
            $temp['state'] = $h->find('td', 3)->innertext;

            $events[] = $temp;
        }
    }
}

print_r($events);
```

Note: You need to include the Simple HTML Dom Parser first

You can then iterate over this events array, to display it however you wish

As common courtesy, I would only provide maybe the first page or 2, and provide a link back to the source website for the full listings

Comment: ok, so I made sure I have the Simple HTML Dom Parser and added the include ("simple_html_dom.php"); but when I run it, it is giving me an error now, 

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/loadsr/public_html/scrape/scrap.php on line 15

Comment: LOL, ya i noticed that, now I get a new error message.

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/loadsr/public_html/scrape/scrap.php on line 15

Comment: Which line is line 15 in your version? Sorry, I should've mentioned this is untested! I normally use this without many problems though!

Comment: this is my line 15 code:

$url = $h->find('td', 4)->find('a', 0); //First link of second cell

Comment: That's because it should be `$url = $h->find('td', 1)->find('a', 0);` as I have above. It's because there isn't a 5th cell, so it's returning false because it can't find it

Comment: I'm trying to get on something so I can test it, but right now, can you try commenting out those 4 lines in a block and seeing what the result is?

Comment: I've managed to test now and got something working. The errors were caused by there being more than one table on the page, that I didn't spot whilst looking through it

Comment: I was going to ask about that as well, how to only capture the middle table, instead of the top two and bottom one. Also how can i chat with you, off stackoverflow, I would like to pick your brain more, if you don't mind. the site I provided you, i had created, I"m some what familiar with coding in php, but just enough to get by. I had email address care to exchange.

Comment: Ahh I was going to suggest using chat on here, but you don't have enough rep. If you provide me with your email address, I'll happily email you. I'm not fond of leaving my email address in plain text on forums! But if you have any questions, it's good just to ask them on SO, there's a lot of people who know the answers, if they haven't been answered already

Comment: well for now you can go here and I can give you my email, then we can communicate via google chat

http://www.trevtech.com/chat/chat.php